# nearly full partition seen on df...is this a problem?

Tags: partitioning, df

Periodically I check my drives to see if any are full.  `df -h` gives:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.6G  2.1M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       457G  124G  311G  29% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
efivarfs        128K  122K  1.5K  99% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/sda1       511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sdc2       922G  458G  417G  53% /media/bob/mybook1
/dev/sdc5       912G  182G  685G  21% /media/bob/mybook2
/dev/sdb3       931G  647G  284G  70% /media/bob/fedora_localhost-live
tmpfs           1.6G  3.2M  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

My question is the `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` partition.  Is this a problem that it is 99% full? If so, how do I fix it.

Thanks

Comment: The relevant partition is:  /sys/firmware/efi/efivars, which shows 99% full

Comment: I don't think that it is a problem, do you experience any? Please provide OS details.

Comment: No problems at all.  System is stable and boots without any problem.

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.  Computer is Dell OptiPlex 7020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` partition is 99% full doesn't necessarily indicate a critical issue as long as your system remains stable and boots without problems.

The efivars partition stores UEFI (Unified Extensible Firmware Interface) variables, which are essential for system boot and configuration. It's typically quite small (ranging from 128kB to 16MB) due to its limited purpose. Filling it up to near capacity shouldn't affect daily usage significantly unless specific variables fail to update or store.

While not causing immediate problems, it's good practice to keep the efivars partition below 90% for potential future updates.

- Identify unused bootloaders by checking for entries using efibootmgr and remove irrelevant ones using `efibootmgr -b <ID>` where `<ID>` is an ID selected from the results of the `efibootmgr` command.
- Increase the efivars partition size **only as a last resort**. Increasing the efivars partition size can cause some entries in the boot menu to be unable to boot.